# Uncaught Error: Cannot assign to a reference or > variable! > at _AstToIrVisitor.visitPropertyWrite

Tags: angular, typescript

I was following an example from angular.io website of creating a form in angular with an input but I am stuck at an error:

> compiler.js:26390 Uncaught Error: Cannot assign to a reference or
>   variable!
>       at _AstToIrVisitor.visitPropertyWrite (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:26611:23)
>       at PropertyWrite.visit (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:4900:24)
>       at convertActionBinding (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:26035:45)
>       at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:28635:22)
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at ViewBuilder._createElementHandleEventFn (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:28631:18)
>       at nodes.(anonymous function) (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:28050:27)
>       at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:28576:22)
>       at Array.map ()
>       at ViewBuilder._createNodeExpressions (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:28575:56)

The only change I made was renaming the "name" to "username".

dashboard.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  username: string;
  submitted = false;

  constructor() { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit() { this.submitted = true; }

}
```

dashboard.component.html

```
<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col col-lg-12">
      <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #usernameForm="ngForm" >
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="username">Name</label>                    

          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
          required
          [(ngModel)]="username" name="name"
          #username="ngModel">

          <div [hidden]="username.valid || username.pristine"
              class="alert alert-danger">
            Name is required
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

What's wrong in the above code?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
[(ngModel)]="username" name="name"
      #username="ngModel">
```

When you do this, you're creating a variable `username` for your template, that refers to the `NgModel` instance. So, when you bind `ngModel` to `username` the compiler thinks you're binding to the reference, not to your component's `username` property, because template variables hide component properties with the same name. Change the name of the reference to `usernameModel` or something like that (and remember to change it wherever you're using it, too, as in the `div` that shows errors) and it should work fine.